# Generating minimal regular expression character classes

Tags: code-golf, string, regular-expression

## Background

**Character classes** are a standard way to indicate a set of characters to match in regular expressions. For example, the class `[ab]` matches a or b, `[a-z]` matches any lower case letter, and `[^a]` matches everything but a. For the purpose of this question, classes can contain:

- a sequence of characters to match, where  the characters `\`, `]`, `-` and `^` must normally be escaped with a `\`.
- a range of characters to match, indicated by separating two characters with a `-`: e.g. `[0-9]`. Note that if `-` is the first or last character in a class then it need not be escaped, as it's not indicating a range.
- a combination of sequences and ranges: e.g. `[ac-fhk-o]`. Note that the class cannot be empty, and if `]` is the first character in the class then it need not be escaped.
- a complement match indicated by the first character in the class being `^`: e.g. `[^a-z]`. Note that if `^` is not the first character in the class, then it need not be escaped.

## Task

Given a non-empty string made up of printable ASCII characters (" " to "~" = 0x20-0x7E), output the *shortest* character class that matches precisely those characters. The string may contain duplicate characters. [Default Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins, with all the standard loopholes forbidden.

## Test cases

```
"the"     => "[the]" or "[eht]" etc
"faced"   => "[ac-f]" or "[c-fa]"
"0-121"   => "[-0-2]" or "[012-]" etc
"]"       => "[]]"
"[-^]"    => "[][^-]" or "[]^[-]"
"[\]"     => "[[-\]]" or "[]\\[]" or "[][\\]"
```

Comment: Can we take input as a list of character codepoints?

Comment: Also, I think requiring printing to STDOUT, and disallowing (for example) returning from a function, is too restrictive. I'd suggest using the [IO defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted that bit from a previous question. There's no reason not to use defaults, so I'll update it.

Comment: Re taking a list of character codepoints, that's less obvious to me (unless there's another default rule I'm missing). After all, there are many ways to indicate multiple characters and we don't want to have to list them all: strings seem to be the simplest here.

Comment: is '[acdef]' valid for 'faced'?

Comment: @Wasif theorically yes but that's not the shortest, so not for the challenge

Comment: @Kaddath is the output size measured??

Comment: @Wasif that's the goal of the challenge, quoting from the question "output the shortest character class that matches precisely those characters"

Comment: That's right. A challenge entry is only valid if it always returns the shortest class possible.

Comment: I think that `^` can never be in the first position of a group, but otherwise it would match any unprintable characters, which is against the rule? Or whether the regex matches invalid characters doesn't matter?

Comment: Since this is code golf, I guess that the shortest answer in most languages would be to brute force through all regexes.

Comment: @user202729 that's right: the output should never contain a ^ at the start of a class unless it's escaped

Comment: @user202729 brute force is fine, but you still have to implement the reverse function to check if a class expands to the correct set of letters

Answer (score 6):

No answers after a few days, so thought I'd have a go. Found it trickier than expected, so the answer's pretty long, but I'm reasonably confident it works. Should be able to trim it a fair bit more.

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>431</s> <s>405</s> 410 bytes

```python
import re,itertools as I
B,M,C,P="\-]^"
s=sorted;x=s({*input()})
d=[ord(x)-i for i,x in enumerate(x)];l=[];i=0
for _,g in I.groupby(d):n=len([*g]);l+=[[x[i]+M+x[i+n-1]],x[i:i+n]][n<4];i+=n
o="".join(s(l,key=lambda i:2*(M in i[::2])+(P in i)-3*(i[0]==M<C not in x)-2*(C in i)))
print("["+re.sub(".",lambda m:B*((x:=m.group())==B or x==P==o[0]or x==M<M*2==o[(i:=m.start()):i+2]in o[1:-1]or x==C in o[1:])+x,o)+C)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZA/b4MwEMV3PoXFZINB@dOhgtwSpgxI2V23guIQJ2BT27TQqp89NUkn351/eu/eDbM7a7V9HsztJvtBG4eMoNIJ47TuLKosOgR7WtKCHiF8SfhrGFiwnhNNPoHFP5FUw@gw@SVBA0ybBk8kkeikDZJ0QlIhocZemMoJ/8PzDhjPJayChXij7UIc0tbocahn3JBMQScUZlHLSd7FwNjEJI/L2D@xStacU19lvuacqd2TF4tBBRrCML1oqbDFHb2KGbqqr5sKyWwT4XJxkSzLNpzE@HjvSLKNsGQrDlDuCqS0W8Z@ec8XD4KQYDBSORyyMDYitWONwzSk/9J9to8wnjLoH/tjQgD2yOeaAI4A2os/mnJXRptlgOVCW1cZfzLiU2y4d9JsnflkD/buvUz8qhPVJC7I7WaHs1QT0idUd9X7FX2MXuGbosvYtAL1M/rUX38)

## Explanation

The overall approach is to:

1. Split the letters into ranges of length at least 4 and individual characters. Note that ranges of length 3 are never necessary (eg. `"[abc]"` is the same length as `"[a-c]"` and `"[]\\[]"` is the same length `"[[-\]]"`) and are sometimes worse (e.g. `"]-./"` is shorter as  `"[]./-]"` than as `"[]\--/]"` or `"[--/\]]"`).
2. Sort the letters and ranges, so `"]"` goes first, otherwise `"-"` goes first, otherwise `"-"` goes last, and with `"^"` as late as posssible. There is no conflict between putting `"]"` first and `"-"` last since `"]--"` is not a valid range.
3. Escape as necessary: `\` always, `]` unless it's first, `^` if it's first, and `-` if it's in the middle (which will only happen if it's the beginning of a range).

## Extra test cases

```python
"-^"      => "[-^]"
"-4]"     => "[]4-]"
"abcde^"  => "[a-e^]"
"XYZ[\\]" => "[X-\]]"
"-./0]"   => "[]\--0]"
"+*,-^"   => "[\^*--]"
"^_`a"    => "[\^-a]"
```

Comment: A few tips: Creating variables for most single-character string like `B,M,C,P="\-]^"` saves a few bytes, `{*input}` is shorter than `set(input())` and you can append to a list by extending with a singleton list (line 4), and `list.extend(v)` is the same as `l+=v`.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZAxb8MgFIR3/wrEBIZESdqhsvOWZMpgKTullV0Th8QGF3DrtOpvT3HdieP4dO8d/S2crXl46t39rrveuoCc4jooF6xtPSo9OiQ7XvA9PwJ@XsgXnHjwkVN1PoIn36k2/RAI/aFJDcK6mox0odHJOqT5iLRBygydcmVQ8UXmLQiZa1glE/HKm4k4LBtnh766kZpmBlpliEgbSfOWgRCj0JIVLB7MLNZS8qiyqKUUZvsYwxiYxALGy4vVhnjS8qu6QVt2VV0inW1SUkxTNGXkOIvFQ0q0WEmAYrtHxobJjntHdD8TlCa90yYQLDBzaumHiuAl5v@pXbZLCRkz6ObVCaUAOxQrjQBHABvD50uxLdLNZBA90T6ULv4WjQU2Mk6yYp3FUjP7N3tyJGUjt5Tt6f3u@7M2I7InVLXl2xW9DzHhi6PLUDcKdTf0YT9/AQ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")